# Setting combined height and width viewport "breakpoints"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using JavaScript to handle breakpoints in a single page, **non-scrollable** application. I want to do various things when changing viewports, such as fire off animations with a JavaScript animation library.

I've assigned the viewports like so:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvOdqZ)

**HTML:**

```
<div class='box'></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var winWidth = '';
var newWinWidth = '';
var winHeight = '';
var newWinHeight = '';

function setWidthBreakpoints(windowWidth) { //matches bootstrap's breakpoints
    if (windowWidth >= 1200) {
        newWinWidth = 'lg';
    } else if (windowWidth >= 992) {
        newWinWidth = 'md';
    } else if (windowWidth >= 768) {
        newWinWidth = 'sm';
    } else {
        newWinWidth = 'xs';
    }
}

function setHeightBreakpoints(windowHeight) {

  if (windowHeight >= 1024) { //more or less arbitrary, may add or remove
      newWinHeight = 'lg';
  } else if (windowHeight >= 480) {
      newWinHeight = 'md';
  } else {
      newWinHeight = 'sm';
  }

}

window.onresize = function () {
    'use strict';
    setWidthBreakpoints($(this).width());
    setHeightBreakpoints($(this).height());


    if (newWinWidth !== winWidth || newWinHeight !== winHeight) {
        onSizeChange();
        winWidth = newWinWidth;
        winHeight = newWinHeight;
    }
};

function onSizeChange() {
    switch(newWinWidth + '|' + newWinHeight) {
    case 'xs|sm':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'yellow')
    case 'xs|md':
    case 'xs|lg':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'purple')
    case 'sm|sm':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'orange')
    case 'sm|md':
    case 'sm|lg':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'purple')
    case 'md|sm':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'green')
    case 'md|md':
    case 'md|lg':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'purple')
    case 'lg|sm':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'blue')
    case 'lg|md':
    case 'lg|lg':
        $('.box').css('background-color', 'purple')
    }
}
```

In the above code, we want anything above a small height to be purple. But we have to repeat ourselves to set it four different times.

I will be supporting IE9 with this application so I chose to use JS animation library GSAP for performance and fallback reasons. This is why I am handling my media query breakpoints in Javascript.

How can I build such a scheme to minimize code repetition? Is there a more elegant way to handle combined height and width breakpoints? Am I doing it wrong? I don't foresee many more height viewports being added to this application, and the width ones are tied to Bootstrap so they won't be changing at all.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "breakpoints"? What code repition do you mean? There is hardly anything there. Also your code isn't runable like this, which is a requirment for codereview. Finally: This is something that may be more appropriate for CSS than JS.

Comment: @RoToRa I have added information in question that answers these questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've never heard of this referred to as "breakpoints," which usually refers to lines of code that you want to automatically pause (break) in a debugger. Perhaps a better term is in order? (I usually hear "snap point" or the like.)

Comment: @fluffy it is a term used by Twitter's Bootstrap front end framework to refer to a set point at which viewport display changes (http://getbootstrap.com/css/), see the section called "Media Queries" under the section called "Grid System"

Comment: @fluffy but fair point, there is some ambiguity in the question title. Unfortunately because of Bootstrap's widespread popularity the term "breakpoint" is probably now a bit too ubiquitous for us to change it to "snap point", but I've edited the title to make it a bit clearer what is meant when the term "breakpoint" is used.

Comment: 'Breakpoint' is fairly well founded in web dev as being a point at which the design, well, breaks, usually when screen dimensions become too large/small :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get rid of `if` chaines (if that is the repition you mean):

```
var WIDTHS = [
    {name: 'xs', max: 768},
    {name: 'sm', max: 992},
    {name: 'md', max: 1200},
    {name: 'lg'}
];

function getRangeName(value, ranges) {
    for (var i = 0, len = ranges.length; i < len; i++) {
        var range = ranges[i];
        if (typeof range.max === "undefined" || value < range.max) {
            return range.name;
        }
    }
}

function setWidthBreakpoints(windowWidth) {
    return getRangeName(windowWidth, WIDTHS);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will add code to make it runnable and refine the question based on your feedback

Comment: @Conor Keep in mind not to modify the code in the original question (although extending it to make it runnable should be ok).

Comment: I added the necessary fixes to make the code runnable and a CodePen. Will also add some more details to the question. Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: @Conor A nice way to say thanks for feedback is to upvote